# wrong results with sum

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm very new at writing `SQL` and am struggling with this code. I have 4 tables and I'm not getting the correct results. I think it may have to do with the `joins` but I'm not sure how to continue.  The quantity * amount is not producing the right number and the `Deprec` Amount and `LTD` amount are repeated on every other line.

```
SELECT pa.BUSINESS_UNIT,
pc.DEPTID,
pa.ASSET_ID,
pa.DESCR,
pa.IN_SERVICE_DT,
pc.COST,
pc.QUANTITY,
sum(pc.COST * pc.QUANTITY) AS Total_Cost,
pb.METHOD,
pb.LIFE,
pdr.DEPR,
pdr.DEPR_LTD

from PS_ASSET pa
inner join PS_COST pc on pc.ASSET_ID = pa.ASSET_ID and pc.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT
inner join PS_BOOK pb on pb.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID and pb.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT
inner join PS_DEPR_RPT pdr on pdr.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID and pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT

where pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0057'
and pa.ASSET_ID = '000000000020'
and pb.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
and pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = '2014'
and pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '12'

group by 
pa.BUSINESS_UNIT,
pc.DEPTID,
pa.ASSET_ID,
pa.DESCR,
pa.IN_SERVICE_DT,
pc.COST,
pc.QUANTITY,
pb.METHOD,
pb.LIFE,
pdr.DEPR,
pdr.DEPR_LTD
```

Here are the results I'm getting:

```
A0057    000000000020    Vehicle Equipment      50    1      650     4.16     8.33
A0057    000000000020    Vehicle Equipment      50    1      650    43.75    87.5
A0057    000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    1000    1    13000     4.16     8.33
A0057    000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    1000    1    13000    43.75    87.5
A0057    000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     100    2     2600     4.16     8.33
A0057    000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     100    2     2600    43.75    87.5
```

I've removed `DeptID`, `Method`, and `Life` from the results, so that they would fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

Get rid of the sum to get find the correct total cost `pc.COST * pc.QUANTITY` AS Total_Cost,

**Problem**

It looks like your query is returning multiple results and then the `group by` is grouping them into one line. The `sum` is then adding all of the results together to give you the unexpected results.

Let me elaborate to make this a little bit more clear. Your tables most likely have more columns than the ones that you have selected. Even if just one table has more columns than you have selected, you may have multiple result rows. Let's just focus on PS_ASSET. I know PS_ASSET has the columns BUSINESS_UNIT, ASSET_ID, DESCR, and IN_SERVICE_DT. Let's say it also has the column ASSET_COLOR.

**Example**

Next, let's give PS_ASSET some fake data. Maybe the table looks like this:

> ```
> BUSINESS_UNIT | ASSET_ID     | DESCR   | IN_SERVICE_DT | ASSET_COLOR
> A0057         | 000000000020 | Vehicle | Equipment     | Red
> A0057         | 000000000020 | Vehicle | Equipment     | Blue
> ```

Because of the color, your results table would actually look like this:

> ```
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     50    1      50     4.16     8.33    red
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     50    1      50     4.16     8.33    blue
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     50    1      50    43.75    87.5     red
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     50    1      50    43.75    87.5     blue
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment   1000    1    1000     4.16     8.33    red
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment   1000    1    1000     4.16     8.33    blue
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment   1000    1    1000    43.75    87.5     red
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment   1000    1    1000    43.75    87.5     blue
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    100    2     200     4.16     8.33    red
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    100    2     200     4.16     8.33    blue
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    100    2     200    43.75    87.5     red
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    100    2     200    43.75    87.5     blue
> ```

**Example Results**

However, your `select` statement does not include the ASSET_COLOR and your `group by` doesn't either. So, the rows with red and blue are grouped together and the `sum` part of `sum(pc.COST * pc.QUANTITY)` adds the `COST*QUANTITY` together. The select and group by of your query applied to the above table would result in:

> ```
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     50    1     100     4.16     8.33    
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment     50    1     100    43.75    87.5     
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment   1000    1    2000     4.16     8.33    
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment   1000    1    2000    43.75    87.5     
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    100    2     400     4.16     8.33    
> A0057   000000000020    Vehicle Equipment    100    2     400    43.75    87.5
> ```

**Finding Correct Results**

Moral of the story, remove the sum and you should get what you are expecting

```
SELECT pa.BUSINESS_UNIT,
pc.DEPTID,
pa.ASSET_ID,
pa.DESCR,
pa.IN_SERVICE_DT,
pc.COST,
pc.QUANTITY,
pc.COST * pc.QUANTITY AS Total_Cost,
pb.METHOD,
pb.LIFE,
pdr.DEPR,
pdr.DEPR_LTD
```

**Summing Results**

So now that you have the correct information for the total_Cost column, what if you really do want to sum up all of that information? Well, because of the reasons above, we can't just add a `sum()` to the front of that column, but we will need to use the `sum()` function and a subquery.

Changing the query into a subquery essentially allows you to work with the columns of the results table and ignore the table structure of the tables you were previously working with. What this means is we can then sum up the total values.

**Query**

```
SELECT p.BUSINESS_UNIT,
p.DEPTID,
p.ASSET_ID,
p.DESCR,
p.IN_SERVICE_DT,
p.COST,
p.QUANTITY,
sum(p.Total_Cost)
p.METHOD,
p.LIFE,
p.DEPR,
p.DEPR_LTD

From ( --Your previous Query Here)

Group by p.BUSINESS_UNIT,
        p.DEPTID,
        p.ASSET_ID,
        p.DESCR,
        p.IN_SERVICE_DT,
        p.COST,
        p.QUANTITY,
        p.METHOD,
        p.LIFE,
        p.DEPR,
        p.DEPR_LTD
```

If the data from the Example Results section was used, this query would return the exact same results as above. This is because there are no duplicate rows in the query. All of the values from each of the rows must be identical in order for the summing to occur *EXCEPT* for any rows in an aggregate function. What is an aggregate function? `Sum` is one example, `min` and `max` are other examples of this. So, every column in the select must either be in an aggregate function or the group by clause for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This is going to be a VERY slow learning curve.  I really appreciate your help with the explanation.

Comment: @Shaves If it's any encouragement, I had never seen sql until about 14 months ago. You will probably get the hang of it faster than you think.

Comment: Jenn.........that did the trick.  Now I just got to get rid of the duplicates in the Depr and Depr_LTD lines and I think I'm good to go

Comment: Jenn....I have another question for you.  Is it possible to only display the total_cost without showing the cost and quantity?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Shaves It is absolutely possible. You will need to leave them in the group by, but you can remove those lines from the select.

Comment: Jenn............If you don't mind, I have 1 more question for you.  Currently, I have 3 lines total cost of $ 50, $ 200, and $1000.  Is it possible to only display 1 line where the TOTAL_COST field would total $ 1250?  Thanks again

Comment: @Shaves I edited my answer to include information that will help you do that. You will need to figure out something to do with DEPR and DEPR_LTD in order for this to work (such as sum or use the min or max or the average)

Answer (score -1):

replace this part

```
sum(pc.COST * pc.QUANTITY) AS Total_Cost
```

by

```
(sum(pc.COST) * sum(pc.QUANTITY)) AS Total_Cost
```

normally this work better